# Non linear regression calculator

Tags: exponential-function, regression, nonlinear-system, online-resources, calculator

Are there any really good non linear regression calculators around the web? Or is something like MATLAB the best solution?

I tried using excel and its solver tool, but it's complete garbage lol. Granted, my modeling formula could be better, but there's got to be something better out there.

I used the model equation: $\mathrm{value}(t) = Ae^{-bt}\cos((\omega)(t)+(\varphi)) + y\text{-intercept} + m(t)$, where $m$ is a slope used in attempt to match the shape of this graph

Here's what I got from excel
[image]

Any ideas what tool I can use for a more accurate regression?

Comment: Are you trying to estimate values of $A$, $b$, $\omega$, $\varphi$ and an intercept? Or only some of those, while treating the others as known? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy that's correct -- trying to estimate all

Comment: ok . . . . $b$ and $\omega$ are the non-linear parts.  The phase shift isn't really a case of nonlinearity, since $A\cos(\omega t + \varphi)$ $= A\cos(\omega t)\sin\varphi + A\sin(\omega t)\cos\varphi$, and one can separately estimate $A\cos\varphi$ and $A\sin\varphi$ by ordinary least squares. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: In my experience, when doing nonlinear regression, the most important thing is getting good initial estimates for the parameters. Once you have that, almost any fitting technique will work. Your plot looks mostly linear, so I would do a linear fit to get $m(t)$ and use that as a start. Also, $\omega$ and $b$ look like they would be pretty small, so I would start them at zero.

Comment: @ kendall : I don't known if this can be helpfull for you : paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales . The case of function $Ae^{-bt}\cos(\omega t+\phi)$ is described pages 66-70 with a numerical example. Your case of function $Ae^{-bt}\cos(\omega t+\phi)+\alpha t+\beta$ would require a complement of study. Applying the algorithm p.66-67 just as it is now should give only the appoximates of $b$ , $\omega$ and $\phi$. Then, a further linear regression (not written in the actual algorithm) involving $A$ , $\alpha$ , $\beta$ should complete the approximates.